# Can not read file when run within jar file

Tags: java, akka, akka-http

I have an akka http service. I simply return the api documentation for a get request. The documentation is in html file.

It all works fine when run within the IDE. When I package it as a jar I get error 'resource not found'. I am not sure why it can not read the html file when hosted in a jar and works fine when in IDE.

Here is the code for the route.

```
private Route topLevelRoute() {
    return pathEndOrSingleSlash(() -> getFromResource("asciidoc/html/api.html"));
}
```

The files are located in resource path.

[image]

Comment: How about changing to  `getFromResource("/asciidoc/html/api.html")`?

Comment: That does not work. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have got this working now.

I am doing this.

```
private Route topLevelRoute() {
 try {
   InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/asciidoc/html/api.html"));
   BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);
   //Get the stream input into string builder
   reader.lines().forEach(s -> strBuild.append(s));

   inputStreamReader.close();
   bufferedReader.close();
   //pass the string builder as string with contenttype set to html
   complete(HttpEntities.create(ContentTypes.TEXT_HTML_UTF8, strBuild.toString()))
 } catch (Exception ex) {
        //Catch any exception here
 }
}
```

Comment: That is not good example for others at all, you are blocking on reading the file. I'd recommend that you figure out your class path problems instead and use the built in directives. If the solution above is what you are going to do, please at least make sure you run it on a separate dispatcher. See http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/scala/dispatchers.html#problem-blocking-on-default-dispatcher for more details.